# Android device cannot connect to localhost

Tags: android, networking

I am developing an app for Android. I have been happily developing it for a while, connecting the phone to the PC using a USB, using 192.168.x.x as the address the code points to log in, etc.

I started my IDE a couple of hours before, and without changing a single comma anywhere, I receive an Exception:

```
10-21 17:15:04.177: W/System.err(24232): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.4:8080 timed out
10-21 17:15:04.177: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-21 17:15:04.187: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-21 17:15:04.187: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at myPackage.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(CustomHttpClient.java:54)
10-21 17:15:04.197: W/System.err(24232):    at myPackage.LoginActivity$3$1.run(LoginActivity.java:113)
```

- I have checked the server is up
- My phone is connected to the same wifi the PC with the server is
- Internet permission is in my manifest
- I do have Internet, since I am writing this here
- My phone has Internet, since I have been accessing the internet with him, via the same WiFi
- Did ipconfig to make sure the IP is correct

i am getting mad... any help? Thank you!

Comment: Is the port 8080 correct? And do you see your request at access log of your app server?

Comment: The port was ok, and I didnt see the request in my server app. But, I fixed it. Was a very strange thing, see answer below. Thanks for commenting, btw.

Answer (score 0):

A very weird thing happened. When I did ipconfig I would swear over the most sacred thing on earth i saw 192.168.1.4. I did it more than one time, always saying 192.168.1.4. After posting this question I did it again...and it showed 192.168.1.3. i changed it in the Android app and now i am able to access server.

Is there some time between an IP has changed and the ipconfig shows it? Because im SURE it said 192.168.1.4 the first 3 times I did it...